# How can you spoof you caller id but not using a voip (your carrier instead)?

Tags: phone, spoofing, simcard

My research:

I found this [security stackexchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211778/how-can-caller-id-be-faked) but it didn't answer my question.

I know that you can do similar things using astresik with voip provider.

I came up on o blog that explain that sim card is computer ect.. [link](https://simhacks.github.io/defcon-21/)

But can you spoof you caller id but not using a voip (your carrier instead)

Comment: There are third party services that allow you to place spoofed calls from a regular phone or smartphone. Basically they provide a gateway to a VOIP platform. Just google spoof caller id or similar.

Comment: @Anonymous I have done the search but no luck. I found the same thing. Can provide me with some links

Comment: It is possible to set the outbound caller id, on outbound calls made over land lines (not VOIP), using equipment designed for this purpose.  For example, see https://www.dialogic.com/support/helpweb/default.aspx/tr1034 for instructions on how to do this using a Dialogic fax board.